# How to add values to a dataframe based on conditions in another dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frame and want to complete one based on the other. First data frame called, df1, has 100 column, A, B, C, D and c(5:100). Second dataframe called df2, is exactly the same but column c(5:100) has a different name and there is no value in there.
Now for every unique value in column A, look at df1, in Column D, where it is "inside", and the value for it is "1" in column c(5:100), then put "I" in data frame called "df2" column c(5:100), if 0 put "O".
I have an example for you, imagine first data frame is like df1 and I want to have the df2 as the result.

```
df1 <- structure(list(A=c("A_1_01", "A_1_01", "A_1_01"), B=c("A", "A", "A"), C=c("1", "1", "1"), D=c("inside", "eating", "sleeping"), "1"=c("1","1","0"), "2"=c("1","0","0"), "3"=c("0","0","1"), "4"=c("0","1","1")), class= "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))
```

```
df2<- structure(list(A=c("A_1_01", "A_1_01", "A_1_01"), B=c("A", "A", "A"), C=c("1", "1", "1"), D=c("inside", "eating", "sleeping"), "1"=c("1","1","0"), "2"=c("1","0","0"), "3"=c("0","0","1"), "4"=c("0","1","1"), "1_Location"=c("I","I", "I"), "2_Location"=c("I","I", "I"), "3_Location"=c("O","O", "O"), "4_Location"=c("O","O", "O")), class= "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))
```

How do I do this using R?

And Thank you, everyone. Now how do I pivot the columns into rows to get the required structure in df3:

```
df3<- structure(list(H=c("1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4"),
                     A=c("A_1_01", "A_1_01", "A_1_01","A_1_01", "A_1_01",
                         "A_1_01","A_1_01", "A_1_01", "A_1_01","A_1_01",
                         "A_1_01", "A_1_01"),
                     B=c("A", "A", "A","A", "A", "A","A", "A", "A","A", "A", "A"),
                     C=c("1", "1", "1","1", "1", "1","1", "1", "1","1", "1", "1"),
                     D=c("inside","inside","inside","inside",
                         "eating","eating","eating","eating",
                         "sleeping","sleeping","sleeping","sleeping"),
                     Value=c(1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1),
                     Location=c("I","I","O","O","I","I","O","O","I","I","O","O")),
                class= "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-12L))
```

Comment: For each unique value in `A`, is there only one `"inside"` in `D`?

Comment: Yes, it is only one inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ifelse` across the selected columns to create `df2`:

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  mutate(across(`1`:`4`, ~ ifelse(.x[D == "inside"] == 1, "I", "0"), .names = "{col}_Location"))

#       A B C        D 1 2 3 4 1_Location 2_Location 3_Location 4_Location
#1 A_1_01 A 1   inside 1 1 0 0          I          I          0          0
#2 A_1_01 A 1   eating 1 0 0 1          I          I          0          0
#3 A_1_01 A 1 sleeping 0 0 1 1          I          I          0          0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create `df2` from `df1` as below. (Note, if `df2` actually is a different frame with columns 1:100 that are different than `df1` [these looked identical in your example), just replace `df2` as the first frame in the inner join)

```
inner_join(
  df1, 
  df1 %>% 
    filter(D=="inside") %>%
    mutate(across(-c(1:4), ~if_else(.x==1, "I", "O"),.names = "{.col}_Location")) %>% 
    dplyr::select("A",ends_with("Location")),
  by="A"
)
```

Output:

```
       A B C        D 1 2 3 4 1_Location 2_Location 3_Location 4_Location
1 A_1_01 A 1   inside 1 1 0 0          I          I          O          O
2 A_1_01 A 1   eating 1 0 0 1          I          I          O          O
3 A_1_01 A 1 sleeping 0 0 1 1          I          I          O          O
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `if/else`

```
library(dplyr)
 df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(`1`:`4`, ~ if(any(D == 'inside' & .x == 1)) "I" else "0", 
   .names = "Location_{.col}"), .by = 'A')
```

-output

```
       A B C        D 1 2 3 4 Location_1 Location_2 Location_3 Location_4
1 A_1_01 A 1   inside 1 1 0 0          I          I          0          0
2 A_1_01 A 1   eating 1 0 0 1          I          I          0          0
3 A_1_01 A 1 sleeping 0 0 1 1          I          I          0          0
```